# Can somebody explain this Maven command to me?

Tags: maven

Can you please explain this command detailedly, please? What is exec? and exec:exec? -Pexperiment? -DconfigFile?

```
mvn exec:exec -Pexperiment -DconfigFile=src/test/resources/configFile/configFile-demo000.js
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 3):

Its runnng the exec goal defined by the exec plug-in using the 'experiment' profile.  The 'configFile' value is also being defined in the command-line as an system property.

Comment: That's hardly "detailedly" as the OP asked for, but you can't safe him from rtfm either! ;-) welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

- `mvn` is the Maven Command
- `exec:exec` is a shortcut for the goal `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec` (version may differ). This is described here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html.
- `-Pexperiment` is telling maven to use a Build Profile called `experiment`. Build Profiles are described here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
- `-DconfigFile=...` is a system property that is being used by maven in the pom file or by a plugin. Maven properties are described here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html. How to configure plugins is described here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html